# Rounding To Nearest Bin

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list of revenue charges that I need to round up *or* down to the nearest bin.

For example, if the only products sold cost the following:

```
import numpy as np
bins = np.array([9.95,19.95,79.95])
```

and I have a few charges like this:

```
x = np.array([6.68, 9.20, 12.5, 18.75, 21.59])
```

I followed [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382594/python-assigning-values-in-a-list-to-bins-by-rounding-up), which is definitely the closest solution:

```
y = np.take(bins,np.digitize(x,bins))
```

I thought leaving the `right=` parameter to the default for `np.digitize`  would accomplish what I needed, but the results are still rounded up:

```
In [10]: y
Out[10]: array([  9.95,   9.95,  19.95,  19.95,  79.95])
```

In my particular case, I need to round up *or* down to the nearest bin. For example, the $12.50 charge is only $2.55 away from $9.95, but the chosen option, $19.95, is $7.45 away.

EDIT

While one answer in the solution I linked to can round both up/down, it appears that method can return inconsistent results, hence this new post.

Comment: @RNar thanks for pointing that out...I was wary of implementing that solution because a comment mentions it produces inconsistent results.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to round to certain values you need to split at their midpoints. Like so:

```
import numpy as np

bins = np.array([9.95,19.95,79.95])
centers = (bins[1:]+bins[:-1])/2

x = np.array([6.68, 9.20, 12.5, 18.75, 21.59])
res = bins[np.digitize(x, centers)]
```

Gives

```
array([  9.95,   9.95,   9.95,  19.95,  19.95])
```